# How to select best k fractions out of n fractions (k<=n) so as to have (numerator sum / denominator sum) maximum?

Tags: number-theory, fractions

**For ex.**
    Given are 4 fractions.
    **4/2, 2/3, 1/2, 10/20**
    I have to select 3 fractions out of these 4 so that the value of (num sum)/(den sum) is maximum. 
    As in this case, selecting 4/2, 2/3, 1/2 will result in (4+2+1)/(2+3+2) = 1 which is maximum.

upon what criteria I can select k fractions which will always result is maximum (nSum/dSum) value. where **nSum** = sum of numerators and **dSum** = sum of denominators.

Comment: It would be interesting to find out the computational complexity of this problerm.

Comment: what would be it's complexity?